# How to use CLJS + Node.js (+ node-webkit)

Tags: node.js, clojurescript, node-webkit

How does one achieve this integration? Mainly the integration with Node because I have been at this for a couple of days, trying stuff out myself and reading blog posts but I can't get it to work. The reason probably being there are no recent blog posts on this.

So my questions are:

- How does one integrate CLJS with Node.js? Mainly how does one take advantage of Node's `require` function?
- After it's working with Node, I.E. one can do `node file.js` on the generated CLJS file and it works, is there anything special one needs to do to integrate correctly with node-webkit?

As an extra, what does `:target :nodejs` actually do in cljsbuild's compile settings?

Also I'd like a working solution. Please do not point me to a blog post or something of the sort because I'm pretty sure I've read all of them and none of them have had any success.

Also, something like the `mies` template by Swannondete would be nice, but made to work with Node and/or node-webkit would be nice. :)

Comment: So what problems are you having exactly?

Comment: @Juhana Edited thepost making it clearer. Is it better?

Comment: All right. Edited it and made a vote to reopen it. Appreciate any help with that. :)

Comment: If you’ve tried to run ClojureScript project on node and failed, please show us your `project.clj` file, `core.cljs` as well, and describe structure of your project. You can easily use `mies` as basic template. I’ve made some working, node.js app in ClojureScript with absolutely no problems. There’s no integration to perform here.
StackOverflow is place where you ask for a solution for particular problems, not for tutorials. Show us your project, tell what’s the problem, so someone can solve. Regarding `require` function, use it normally. Just call `(js/require "libname")` and you’re done